# dynamic var in LinQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need something equivalent to `dynamic` with linq.
I want to return all the active data from the type T in the database. The problem is that not all the tables have an "Active". So i need something like:

```
public static List<T> get<T>() where T : class
{
    if (typeof(T).GetProperty("Activo")!=null)
    {
        return (from c in context.Set<T>().AsQueryable()
                where c.Activo //I know for sure it have an Activo property
                select c).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
    return (from c in context.Set<T>().AsQueryable()
            select c).ToList();
    }         
}
```

How can I force LinQ to use the "Activo" property? Like using a `dynamic`variable

An interface is not possible because i need to pass to the method type that are unable to implement it

Comment: How can i overload and distinguish both loads if they both have no arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
public static List<T> get<T>() where T : class
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var prop = type.GetProperty("Activo")
    if (prop!=null)
    {
        return (from c in context.Set<T>().AsQueryable()
            where prop.GetValue(c, null)=="xyz123"
            select c).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return (from c in context.Set<T>().AsQueryable()
            select c).ToList();
    }         
}
```

I don't like using reflection, though, because if you ever change the property's name, reflection code will break.  I prefer to hook an interfact implementing a particular property to the class, and then see if my instance (to compare) implements that interface.

Comment: Is it nicer to see if an instance have an interface than to see if it has a property?

And it give me the following exeption: ` LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

Comment: Checking to see if an instance implements a particular interface is far, far cleaner.  As for the exception - unfortunately you will have to add .ToList() after .AsQueryable(), which means the entire result set is pulled into RAM before evaluating the property.  You may or may not want that to happen.  Your example didn't indicate that the result was coming from Linq-to-Entities.  That may complicate the "interface" approach as well.